# Manipulating value in a column based on a rule

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns -`A, B and C` in a  pandas dataframe. What i want to do is, where ever `A is not null AND B|C are not null`, that row in `A` should be set to `null`.

```
if(dffinal['A'].loc[dffinal['A'].notnull()] & 
    (dffinal['B'].loc[dffinal['B'].notnull()] | 
    dffinal['C'].loc[dffinal['C'].notnull()])):
    dffinal['A'] = np.nan
```

this is the error I'm getting: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.A.notna() & (df.B.notna()|df.C.notna()),'A']=np.nan
```

Answer (score 2):

Here first condition is not necessary, so solution should be simplify:

```
dffinal = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[np.nan,np.nan,4,5,5,np.nan],
         'B':[7,np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan],
         'C':[1,3,5,7,np.nan,np.nan],
})

print (dffinal)
     A    B    C
0  NaN  7.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  3.0
2  4.0  NaN  5.0
3  5.0  4.0  7.0
4  5.0  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN

mask = (dffinal['B'].notnull() | dffinal['C'].notnull())

dffinal.loc[mask, 'A'] = np.nan
print (dffinal)
     A    B    C
0  NaN  7.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  NaN  4.0  7.0
4  5.0  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Same output like in first condition:

```
mask = dffinal['A'].notnull() & (dffinal['B'].notnull() | dffinal['C'].notnull())

dffinal.loc[mask, 'A'] = np.nan
print (dffinal)
     A    B    C
0  NaN  7.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  NaN  4.0  7.0
4  5.0  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN
```